# How to listen to doorbell events in Alexa smart home skill( Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

This is my first smart home skill, and this could be a dummies question

I am trying to create a smart home skill to integrate with doorbell using the following interface.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-doorbelleventsource.html

I have done the account linking with manufacture's cloud with Alexa. Also, done responding discover directive and state report directive in Lambda.

However, still confusing part is how to write a handler in Alexa Skill lambda to listen to doorbell events and state change events?Is there any endpoint available to listen to device events?

Anyone could advise me how to achieve this?

Note

I got the point of sending events to the event Gateway described here.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html

However, as per my understanding, this is something we manually send to the Alexa cloud to announce the event to Alexa enabled device. But, it won't happen whenever there is a door press event or motion detection happen in manufacturer cloud or doorbell physical device.

My understanding is Alexa cloud integrates with the manufacturer cloud to get the information which we need as we already did the account linking. I assume Alexa cloud knows how to communicates with manufacturers cloud, and we only have to focus on handling Lambda to announce to Alexa enabled device.